# Why doesn't router.refresh() update my dropdown in Next.js 13, while it updates other components?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

**Body**:

I'm working on a Next.js 13 project where I have two client components: `AddFrequentIngreso` and `AddIngreso`. The `AddFrequentIngreso` component is responsible for adding frequent income sources to a database, and the `AddIngreso` component has a dropdown that should display these frequent income sources.

```js
// AddFrequentIngreso.tsx
'use client';
// ... (rest of the code)
const handleAddFrequentIngreso = async () => {
  // ... (rest of the code)
  // Emit custom event to notify that a new ingreso has been added
  const event = new CustomEvent('frequentIngresoAdded');
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
  
  router.refresh();
};
```

```js
// AddIngreso.tsx
'use client';
// ... (rest of the code)
useEffect(() => {
  // ... (rest of the code)
  // Added event listener for custom event 'frequentIngresoAdded'
  window.addEventListener('frequentIngresoAdded', fetchFrequentIngresos);
}, []);
```

When I add a new frequent income source using `AddFrequentIngreso`, I want the dropdown in `AddIngreso` to update automatically without requiring a manual page refresh. I tried using `router.refresh()` in `AddFrequentIngreso` after successfully adding a new income source. While this approach updates other components on the page, the dropdown in `AddIngreso` remains unchanged.

**What Each Component Does:**

- `AddFrequentIngreso`: Adds a new frequent income source to the database.
- `AddIngreso`: Allows the user to add an income entry. It has a dropdown that should list all frequent income sources.

Because `router.refresh()` didn't work for the dropdown, I resorted to using event listeners as a workaround. However, I'm curious to know why `router.refresh()` worked for other components but not for this dropdown. Is it because it's a client component? Does Next.js 13 offer a way to update client components specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are both of these components on the same page? Having more code would help to understand what's happening.

I'm making some guesses here:

- Both components are on the same page
- Calling `AddFrequentIngreso` updates a backend database
- `AddIngreso` loads the state from the backend database at page load
- `AddIngreso` doesn't have any real-time connection to the database

If all of that is true, then your two options are:

1. Manage the state of `AddIngreso` on the client side. Your event is one way of doing that. Another way that might make things easier would be to use the `useState` [event hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState).
2. Set up the `AddIngreso` component to have a "real-time" connection to the database (e.g. [Supabase Realtime](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime)).

I'd suggest using the `useState` hook, something like this:

```
const [freqIncomeSources, setFreqIncomeSources] = useState(0); // I don't know what type the freqIncomeSources are, so I've made them numbers.

// AddFrequentIngreso.tsx
'use client';
// ... (rest of the code)
const handleAddFrequentIngreso = async () => {
    // ... (rest of the code)
    setFreqIncomeSources(new_state);
};
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for; I will try your suggestions. Thank you so much for your insights